# C\C++: Initialize ASCII special char?

Tags: c++, c, char, ascii

How do you initialize special ASCII chars, for example EOT (0x04), ENQ(0x05)?

```
char CHAR1 = '\EOT';
char CHAR2 = '\ENQ';
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply assign char to its hexadecimal value:

```
char CHAR1 = 0x04;
```

Is this correct ? - no the way you initialize it is not correct as compiler expects one escape character after '\'

Answer (score 10):

You can put character code into the variable:

```
char CHAR1 = 4;
char CHAR2 = 5;
```

You can also use escape sequences which you'll find [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Answer (score 5):

By hex or octal, there is no support for their names. `'\x04'` eg.

Comment: But you can add the names yourself: `namespace ascii { static const char EOT(0x04); static const char ENQ(0x05); }`