# Multiple keys are not working

Tags: c++, opengl

I am facing a problem with keys by using `freeglut` functions. All keys are working fine except `ctrl+alt+D`. I don't know why it's not working what I'm doing wrong.
This is Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
using namespace std;

void Display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void SpecialKeys(int key, int xpos, int ypos) {

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) {
        cout << "up key press" << endl;
    }

    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {

        cout << "down key press" << endl;
    }

    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {

        cout << "Right key press" << endl;

    }
    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) {

        cout << "left key press" << endl;

    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void KeysFun(unsigned char key, int xpos, int ypos) {

    if (key == 'a' || key == 'a') {
        cout << "A Key press" << endl;
    }

    else if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {

        int mod = glutGetModifiers();

        if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT) {

            cout << "Alt+S press" << endl;
        }

    }

    else if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {

        int mod = glutGetModifiers();
        int mod2 = glutGetModifiers();
        if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL && mod2== GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT) {

            cout << "CTRL+Alt+D press" << endl;
        }

    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void init(void) {

    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

}


int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("Frame");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeysFun);
    glutSpecialFunc(SpecialKeys);
    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you press CTRL+D `key` doesn't equal `'d' or 'D'` it equals to EOT End of transmission and equal to this `key == 0x04` (more [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014000/c-c-initialize-ascii-special-char)) so you need add to your if expression  else

```
if (key == 'd' || key == 'D' || key == 0x04)
```

next when you press ALT and CTRL simultaneously `glutGetModifiers()` will return you combination of any of the following symbolic bitmasks: GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT... more [info here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glutgetmodifiers)

resulting if block for button d press may look like this:

```
else if (key == 'd' || key == 'D' || key == 0x04) {
    int mod = glutGetModifiers();
    if (mod == (GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL|GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT)) {
      cout << "CTRL+Alt+D press" << endl;
    }
}
```

Works for me on Linux.

Comment: Control-D shouldn't cause EOT on MS Windows (see backslash in `#include`), at least not on any of the shells I know. I'm still curious if this helps fixing the issues.

Comment: @segevara where i can find codes of these keys like 0x04 for D

Comment: @segevara  what is eot?

Comment: @hamel123 I'm note sure that it means EOT for Windows OS as Ulrich Eckhardt mentioned but you can find code e.g. [here](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm) info about end-of-Transmission character you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character)

Comment: @segevara i'm using that code but it's not working Ctrl+Alt+D nothing print i'm using windows

Comment: when I click `numpad_2` while holding `down + right` arrow keys, glfw does not register `numpad_2`, but it does `numpad_3` for example, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have code for this but you could set up key callback and if another key has been pressed and not released then you have your case. GLFW supports key callback which is the method that should be used. However I don't know about freeGLUT but it should have key callback implemented.