# Opengl Mouse click on rectangle

Tags: c++, opengl

Guys i am facing a problem in this program by using glut mouse function. What i am doing a rectangle is drawn on the screen and in mouse function i convert pixels coordinate to world coordinates with the width of 600 and height 500 what i want when user click on given rectangle the color would be red but how i perform this task how to determine mouse click with these rectangles.
Code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include<GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    float xWorldCoordinate = 0.0f;
    float yWorldCoordinate = 0.0f;
    float r = 0.0f;
    float g = 0.0f;
    float b = 0.0f;
    float r1 = 0.0f;
    float g1 = 0.0f;
    float b1 = 0.0f;
    bool isRed = false;

    void init(void) {

        glClearColor(31.0f / 255, 28.0f / 255, 44.0f / 255, 0.0f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    }

    void MouseButton(int button, int action, int xPixel, int yPixel) {

        if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && action == GLUT_DOWN) {
            yPixel = 500 - yPixel;
            xWorldCoordinate = (xPixel / 600.0f) * 2;
            yWorldCoordinate = (yPixel / 400.0f) * 2;
            xWorldCoordinate = -1 + xWorldCoordinate;
            yWorldCoordinate = -1 + yWorldCoordinate;

            int index1 = 0;
            int index2 = 0;
            //Index1
            glReadPixels(xPixel, yPixel, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index1);// Read pixel under mouse's cursor and read information from stencil buffer to index when it rectangle index should be equal to 1


            if (index1 == 1) {
                isRed = !isRed;
                if (isRed) {
                    r = 0.0f;

                }
                else {
                    r = 1.0f;
                }


                //Index 2
            //  glReadPixels(xPixel, yPixel, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index2);
            }
        }

        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void Rectangles(void) {

        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, -1); //set front and back function and reference value for stencil testing
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f(r, g, b);
        glVertex2f(-0.1f, 0.1f);
        glVertex2f(-0.1f, -0.1f);
        glVertex2f(0.1f, -0.1f);
        glVertex2f(0.1f, 0.1f);
        glEnd();

        //2nd Rectangle
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 2, -1);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(r1, g1, b1);
        glVertex2f(0.66f, 0.84f);
        glVertex2f(0.87f, 0.84f);
        glVertex2f(0.87f, 0.66f);
        glVertex2f(0.66f, 0.66f);
        glEnd();
    }
    void Display(void) {
        glClearStencil(0); // specifies the index used by glClear to clear the stencil buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
        glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        Rectangles();
        glFlush();
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_STENCIL); //Bit mask to select a window with a stencil buffer.
        glutInitWindowSize(600, 500);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
        glutCreateWindow("Mouse");
        init();
        glutDisplayFunc(&Display);
        glutMouseFunc(&MouseButton);
        glutMainLoop();

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Am I right that you're trying to determine if you clicking on rectangle when you click?

Comment: @segevara yes exactly when click it change color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can use GLUT_STENCIL by this you can indicate all object on you're scene by index

```
 #if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
  #include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
  #include <GL\freeglut.h>
#endif
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using namespace std;

    float xWorldCoordinate = 0.0f;
    float yWorldCoordinate = 0.0f;
    float r = 0.0f;
    float g = 0.0f;
    float b = 0.0f;
    float r1 = 0.0f;
    float g1 = 0.0f;
    float b1 = 0.0f;
    bool isRed = false;
    bool isBlue = false;
    void init(void) {

        glClearColor(31.0f / 255, 28.0f / 255, 44.0f / 255, 0.0f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    }

    void MouseButton(int button, int action, int xPixel, int yPixel) {

        if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && action == GLUT_DOWN) {
            yPixel = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) - yPixel;

            int * index = new int[1];
            //Index1
            glReadPixels(xPixel, yPixel, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, index);// Read pixel under mouse's cursor and read information from stencil buffer to index when it rectangle index should be equal to 1


            if (index[0] == 1) {
                isRed = !isRed;
                if (isRed) {
                    r = 1.0f;

                }
                else {
                    r = 0.0f;
                }
                //Index 2
            //  glReadPixels(xPixel, yPixel, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index2);
          }else if(index[0] == 2){
            isBlue = !isBlue;
            if (isBlue) {
                b1 = 1.0f;

            }
            else {
                b1 = 0.0f;
            }
          }
          delete index;
        }

        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void Rectangles(void) {

        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, -1); //set front and back function and reference value for stencil testing
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f(r, g, b);
        glVertex2f(-0.1f, 0.1f);
        glVertex2f(-0.1f, -0.1f);
        glVertex2f(0.1f, -0.1f);
        glVertex2f(0.1f, 0.1f);
        glEnd();

        //2nd Rectangle
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 2, -1);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(r1, g1, b1);
        glVertex2f(0.66f, 0.84f);
        glVertex2f(0.87f, 0.84f);
        glVertex2f(0.87f, 0.66f);
        glVertex2f(0.66f, 0.66f);
        glEnd();
    }
    void Display(void) {
        glClearStencil(0); // specifies the index used by glClear to clear the stencil buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
        glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        Rectangles();
        glFlush();
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_STENCIL); //Bit mask to select a window with a stencil buffer.
        glutInitWindowSize(600, 500);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
        glutCreateWindow("Mouse");
        init();
        glutDisplayFunc(&Display);
        glutMouseFunc(&MouseButton);
        glutMainLoop();

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

It works for me on Mac but I think should work with freeglut too

Comment: thanks for answer it works can you help me on my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310028/opengl-multiple-keys-are-not-working

Comment: i don't understand how this code work `glReadPixels(xPixel, yPixel - 1, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX,GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index)` . I know parameters of this function but in y coordinate why you write `yPixel - 1`  . You could also write only  `yPixel `  why you write `-1` , How you write width & height `1`. After that last argument `data`  you write `&index` how it automatically initialize value to 1 and return address of 1 Can you explain it I’m confuse in this line

Comment: i edited my question code if now i make two rectangles than how should it work can you help me..

Comment: @hamel123 actually you're right it unneeded `-1` for `yPixel`.   glReadPixels can read info from group of pixels which you're indicating by interesting rectangle with start point (x,y) and appropriate height and width in our case wee want read info only from one pixel so `height and width` is 1. Also glReadPixels read info in buffer which you're indicating in arguments in our case we want just one number case we read only one pixel so I've give to glReadPixels adress of variable to where I need it put info from stencil buffer.

Comment: @hamel123 I've just edited code for two rectangles so let me know if it works for you

Comment: I've just changed 500 to glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) in this line `yPixel = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) - yPixel;` now height of window is calculating dynamically. Also I see xWorldCoordinate, yWorldCoordinate variables I don't really see for what you need it maybe unused variables and it'll better eliminate remove them.

Comment: in glReadPixels does every time we give argument of width and height 1 when use stencil buffer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103435/discussion-between-hamel123-and-segevara).